# не запускается open server panel

Tags: javascript, openserver

Запустил в браузере файлы через папку localhost [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом вернулся в OSPanel, где попытался запустить Open Server Panel, появился флажочек, нажал "запустить" и такая вот ошибка. Что делать ?)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видимо на компьютере уже стоит какой-то сервер (м.б. на докере или отдельно) и он запущен.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы просто молодец)) в моей версии ответа было хамство и негодование из-за тупости автора..)) и так всегда) у вас же спокойствие и ответ без эмоций, всегда.. респект вам! p.s. я за вами год наблюдаю)

Answer (score 0):

Все получилось)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

https://techblog.sdstudio.top/blog/open-server-i-zaniatyi-port-443-vmware

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)